How to prefix url paths in scss files, used in Vue 3 app, at build time, with absolute address defined in env file
I'm building a web component using Vue 3 / Vite (let's call it widget).
I intend to distribute my widget to many eshops.
My scss files use the following:
background-image: url("/images/edit.svg");

This is ok for development. However, i need to prefix the path of the image with the absolute URL at build time. Because, obviously, the image at that path will not be found in the target eshops that use my widget. I need to use absolute URL to where i serve these static assets.
For the script part of my Vue app, i just use:
export const assetUrl = (uri: string) => {
  return import.meta.env.VITE_ASSET_URL + uri
}

And then i use it like this:
<img :src="assetUrl('/images/bla.png')"

But I am not able to figure out, how to prefix those relative paths in scss files with the absolute url from env file.
Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Give a try to this one: https://www.lichter.io/articles/nuxt3-vue3-dynamic-images/

Since i wasted way too much time trying to solve this to no avail..
I added this to my bash script which i use to build and deploy my widget:
...
# Update _env.scss with deployment values.
sed -i "/^\s*\$asset_url:/ s|'.*'|'${VITE_ASSET_URL}\/${GIT_TAG}'|" _env.scss

echo "Building version: $GIT_TAG"
vite build

# Revert _env.scss.
#sed -i "/^\s*\$asset_url:/ s|'.*'|''|" _env.scss
...

And in all my scss files i use:
background-image: url($asset_url + "/images/edit.svg");

It's quick and dirty, but it works... What didn't work for me is trying countless variations of vite config with loaders, preprocessors, plugins etc..
